# Solidty smart contract blacklist function

Tags: solidity, contract

Trying to merge 2 smart contracts and having some issues. I just want to move my blacklist function from an old contract to my new one. I'll include the line of code. I need adding as I've done the rest just can't find where to put it. In the old contract it was under the `_transfer` function however my new code doesn't have this exact function.

I'll include the full contract below. the line of code I need adding to make the blacklist function work is:

```
require(!_isBlackList[from] && !_isBlackList[to],"You are black listed by Owner");
```

And it needs to sit somewhere in the following code:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: unlicensed
 
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
 
/**
 * BEP20 standard interface
 */
 
interface IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
 
abstract contract Ownable {
    address internal owner;
    address private _previousOwner;
    uint256 private _lockTime;
 
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
 
    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner =_owner;
    }
 
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner(msg.sender), "!OWNER"); _;
    }
 
    function isOwner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return account == owner;
    }
 
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }
 
    function getUnlockTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _lockTime;
    }
 
    function Ownershiplock(uint256 time) public virtual onlyOwner {
        _previousOwner = owner;
        owner = address(0);
        _lockTime = block.timestamp + time;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, address(0));
    }
 
    function Ownershipunlock() public virtual {
        require(_previousOwner == msg.sender, "You don't have permission to unlock");
        require(block.timestamp > _lockTime , "Contract is locked");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, _previousOwner);
        owner = _previousOwner;
    }
}
 
/**
 * Router Interfaces
 */
 
interface IDEXFactory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}
 
interface IDEXRouter {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WWBNB() external pure returns (address);
 
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
 
    function addLiquidityWBNB(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountWBNBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountWBNB, uint liquidity);
 
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
 
    function swapExactWBNBForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
 
    function swapExactTokensForWBNBSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}
 
/**
 * Contract Code
 */
 
contract ZelBNB is IBEP20, Ownable {
 
    address WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    address DEAD = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    address ZERO = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
 
    string constant _name = "ZelBNB"; // 
    string constant _symbol = "ZBNB"; // 
    uint8 constant _decimals = 9;
    uint256 _totalSupply = 1 * 10**6 * 10**_decimals;
 
    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) public isFeeExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) public isTxLimitExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isBlackList;
    
 
    // Detailed Fees
    uint256 public liquidityFee;
    uint256 public devFee;
    uint256 public marketingFee;
    uint256 public buybackFee;
    uint256 public totalFee;
 
    uint256 public BuyliquidityFee    = 3;
    uint256 public BuydevFee          = 0;
    uint256 public BuymarketingFee    = 5;
    uint256 public BuybuybackFee      = 2;
    uint256 public BuytotalFee        = BuyliquidityFee + BuydevFee + BuymarketingFee + BuybuybackFee;
 
    uint256 public SellliquidityFee    = 3;
    uint256 public SelldevFee          = 0;
    uint256 public SellmarketingFee    = 5;
    uint256 public SellbuybackFee      = 2;
    uint256 public SelltotalFee        = SellliquidityFee + SelldevFee + SellmarketingFee + SellbuybackFee;
 
    // Max wallet & Transaction
    uint256 public _maxBuyTxAmount = _totalSupply / (100) * (2); // 1%
    uint256 public _maxSellTxAmount = _totalSupply / (100) * (2); // 1%
    uint256 public _maxWalletToken = _totalSupply / (100) * (2); // 1%

    // Fees receivers
    address public autoLiquidityReceiver = 0xF3902ad7681324F723CE91760B252B4bDf594517;
    address public marketingFeeReceiver = 0x9d01b64acdbef3E0DB64B2f4bFC092a68218b2F3;
    address public devFeeReceiver = 0xF3902ad7681324F723CE91760B252B4bDf594517;
    address public buybackFeeReceiver = 0x9d01b64acdbef3E0DB64B2f4bFC092a68218b2F3;
 
    IDEXRouter public router;
    address public pair;
 
    bool public swapEnabled = true;
    uint256 public swapThreshold = _totalSupply / 1000 * 1; // 0.1%
    uint256 public maxSwapSize = _totalSupply / 100 * 1; //1%
    uint256 public tokensToSell;
 
    bool inSwap;
    modifier swapping() { inSwap = true; _; inSwap = false; }
 
    constructor () Ownable(msg.sender) {
        router = IDEXRouter(0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1);
        pair = IDEXFactory(router.factory()).createPair(WBNB, address(this));
        _allowances[address(this)][address(router)] = type(uint256).max;
 
        isFeeExempt[msg.sender] = true;
        isTxLimitExempt[msg.sender] = true;
 
        _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
 
    receive() external payable { }
 
    function totalSupply() external view override returns (uint256) { return _totalSupply; }
    function decimals() external pure override returns (uint8) { return _decimals; }
    function symbol() external pure override returns (string memory) { return _symbol; }
    function name() external pure override returns (string memory) { return _name; }
    function getOwner() external view override returns (address) { return owner; }
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) { return _balances[account]; }
    function allowance(address holder, address spender) external view override returns (uint256) { return _allowances[holder][spender]; }
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _allowances[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
 
    function approveMax(address spender) external returns (bool) {
        return approve(spender, type(uint256).max);
    }
 
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        return _transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }
 
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        if(_allowances[sender][msg.sender] != type(uint256).max){
            _allowances[sender][msg.sender] = _allowances[sender][msg.sender] - amount;
        }
 
        return _transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
 
    function _transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        if(inSwap){ return _basicTransfer(sender, recipient, amount); }
 
        if(sender == pair){
            buyFees();
        }
 
        if(recipient == pair){
            sellFees();
        }
 
        if (sender != owner && recipient != address(this) && recipient != address(DEAD) && recipient != pair || isTxLimitExempt[recipient]){
            uint256 heldTokens = balanceOf(recipient);
            require((heldTokens + amount) <= _maxWalletToken,"Total Holding is currently limited, you can not buy that much.");
            }
 
        // Checks max transaction limit
        if(sender == pair){
            require(amount <= _maxBuyTxAmount || isTxLimitExempt[recipient], "TX Limit Exceeded");
        }
 
        if(recipient == pair){
            require(amount <= _maxSellTxAmount || isTxLimitExempt[sender], "TX Limit Exceeded");
            
        }   

        //Exchange tokens
        if(shouldSwapBack()){ swapBack(); }
 
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender] - amount;
 
        uint256 amountReceived = shouldTakeFee(sender) ? takeFee(recipient, amount) : amount;
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient] + amountReceived;
 
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amountReceived);
        return true;
    }
 
    function _basicTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender] - amount;
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient] + (amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
 
    // Internal Functions
    function buyFees() internal{
        liquidityFee    = BuyliquidityFee;
        devFee   = BuydevFee;
        marketingFee    = BuymarketingFee;
        buybackFee      = BuybuybackFee;
        totalFee        = BuytotalFee;
    }
 
    function sellFees() internal{
        liquidityFee    = SellliquidityFee;
        devFee   = SelldevFee;
        marketingFee    = SellmarketingFee;
        buybackFee      = SellbuybackFee;
        totalFee        = SelltotalFee;
    }
 
    function shouldTakeFee(address sender) internal view returns (bool) {
        return !isFeeExempt[sender];
    }
 
    function takeFee(address sender, uint256 amount) internal returns (uint256) {
        uint256 feeAmount = amount / 100 * (totalFee);
 
        _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)] + (feeAmount);
        emit Transfer(sender, address(this), feeAmount);
 
        return amount - (feeAmount);
    }
 
    function shouldSwapBack() internal view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender != pair
        && !inSwap
        && swapEnabled
        && _balances[address(this)] >= swapThreshold;
    }
 
    function swapBack() internal swapping {
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        if(contractTokenBalance >= maxSwapSize){
            tokensToSell = maxSwapSize;            
        }
        else{
            tokensToSell = contractTokenBalance;
        }
 
        uint256 amountToLiquify = tokensToSell / (totalFee) * (liquidityFee) / (2);
        uint256 amountToSwap = tokensToSell - (amountToLiquify);
 
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = WBNB;
 
        uint256 balanceBefore = address(this).balance;
 
        router.swapExactTokensForWBNBSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amountToSwap,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
 
        uint256 amountBNB = address(this).balance - (balanceBefore);
 
        uint256 totalBNBFee = totalFee - (liquidityFee / (2));
 
        uint256 amountBNBLiquidity = amountBNB * (liquidityFee) / (totalBNBFee) / (2);
        uint256 amountBNBbuyback = amountBNB * (buybackFee) / (totalBNBFee);
        uint256 amountBNBMarketing = amountBNB * (marketingFee) / (totalBNBFee);
        uint256 amountBNBDev = amountBNB - amountBNBLiquidity - amountBNBbuyback - amountBNBMarketing;
 
        (bool MarketingSuccess,) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 500}("");
        require(MarketingSuccess, "receiver rejected WBNB transfer");
        (bool buybackSuccess,) = payable(buybackFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBbuyback, gas: 500}("");
        require(buybackSuccess, "receiver rejected WBNB transfer");
        (bool devSuccess,) = payable(devFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBDev, gas: 500}("");
        require(devSuccess, "receiver rejected WBNB transfer");
 
        addLiquidity(amountToLiquify, amountBNBLiquidity);
    }
 
    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 BNBAmount) private {
    if(tokenAmount > 0){
            router.addLiquidityWBNB{value: BNBAmount}(
                address(this),
                tokenAmount,
                0,
                0,
                autoLiquidityReceiver,
                block.timestamp
            );
            emit AutoLiquify(BNBAmount, tokenAmount);
        }
    }
 
    // External Functions
    function checkSwapThreshold() external view returns (uint256) {
        return swapThreshold;
    }
 
    function checkMaxWalletToken() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _maxWalletToken;
    }
 
    function checkMaxBuyTxAmount() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _maxBuyTxAmount;
    }
 
    function checkMaxSellTxAmount() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _maxSellTxAmount;
    }
 
    function isNotInSwap() external view returns (bool) {
        return !inSwap;
    }
 
    // Only Owner allowed
    function setBuyFees(uint256 _liquidityFee, uint256 _buybackFee, uint256 _marketingFee, uint256 _devFee) external onlyOwner {
        BuyliquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        BuybuybackFee = _buybackFee;
        BuymarketingFee = _marketingFee;
        BuydevFee = _devFee;
        BuytotalFee = _liquidityFee + (_buybackFee) + (_marketingFee) + (_devFee);
    }
 
    function setSellFees(uint256 _liquidityFee, uint256 _buybackFee, uint256 _marketingFee, uint256 _devFee) external onlyOwner {
        SellliquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        SellbuybackFee = _buybackFee;
        SellmarketingFee = _marketingFee;
        SelldevFee = _devFee;
        SelltotalFee = _liquidityFee + (_buybackFee) + (_marketingFee) + (_devFee);
    }
 
    function setFeeReceivers(address _autoLiquidityReceiver, address _marketingFeeReceiver, address _buybackFeeReceiver, address _devFeeReceiver) external onlyOwner {
        autoLiquidityReceiver = _autoLiquidityReceiver;
        marketingFeeReceiver = _marketingFeeReceiver;
        buybackFeeReceiver = _buybackFeeReceiver;
        devFeeReceiver = _devFeeReceiver;
    }
 
    function setSwapBackSettings(bool _enabled, uint256 _percentage_min_base10000, uint256 _percentage_max_base10000) external onlyOwner {
        swapEnabled = _enabled;
        swapThreshold = _totalSupply / (10000) * (_percentage_min_base10000);
        maxSwapSize = _totalSupply / (10000) * (_percentage_max_base10000);
    }
 
    function setIsFeeExempt(address holder, bool exempt) external onlyOwner {
        isFeeExempt[holder] = exempt;
    }
 
    function setIsTxLimitExempt(address holder, bool exempt) external onlyOwner {
        isTxLimitExempt[holder] = exempt;
    }
 
    function setMaxWalletPercent_base1000(uint256 maxWallPercent_base1000) external onlyOwner {
        _maxWalletToken = _totalSupply / (1000) * (maxWallPercent_base1000);
    }
 
    function setMaxBuyTxPercent_base1000(uint256 maxBuyTXPercentage_base1000) external onlyOwner {
        _maxBuyTxAmount = _totalSupply / (1000) * (maxBuyTXPercentage_base1000);
    }
 
    function setMaxSellTxPercent_base1000(uint256 maxSellTXPercentage_base1000) external onlyOwner {
        _maxSellTxAmount = _totalSupply / (1000) * (maxSellTXPercentage_base1000);
    }
    
    function isBlackList(address Account)external view returns(bool){
        return _isBlackList[Account];
    }

     function SetBlackListAccountStatus(address Account, bool status)external onlyOwner(){
        _isBlackList[Account] = status;
    }
 
    // Stuck Balances Functions
    function rescueToken(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        return IBEP20(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, tokens);
    }
 
    function clearStuckBalance(uint256 amountPercentage) external onlyOwner {
        uint256 amountBNB = address(this).balance;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amountBNB * amountPercentage / 100);
    }
 
event AutoLiquify(uint256 amountBNB, uint256 amountTokens);
 
}
```

any help would be great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

GM there!

`_transfer` is an internal function provided by the `ERC20` Openzeppelin library, you can override it in the contract and add your lines in the contract like this

```js
function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
    require(!_isBlackList[from] && !_isBlackList[to],"You are black listed by Owner");
    super._transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers~

Comment: Thanks will give this a go soon, however do you know where abouts it should go in my code above that i provieded as i have some other functions like max tx etc would this effect these? thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Also having some compiler errors when using that blacklist line, would you be willing to help me implement and can tip?

Comment: on that blacklist line, change "from" to "sender", and "to" into "recipient" :)

Comment: thats great, seems to have sorted some more stuff using the following     function transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(!_isBlackList[sender] && !_isBlackList[recipient],"You are black listed by Owner");
    } however still getting this error Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
--> contracts/BTEST.sol:231:58:

Comment: I don't think that concerns the function `_transfer` more like from your other functions, basically it says there's parameter that you defined but never used

Check line 231 there column 58 to see what variable it is specifically

Comment: Amazing and last time ill reply, got the function blacklist working great however there is a swap issue as follows: <code>instrument.js:108 Call threw error Object Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)", </code> not sure how to fix this any ideas would be great thanks